# In whats case should use auto type?

Tags: c++, lambda, auto, c++14, std-function

I have some questions regarding when use `auto`

1. Explicit, it is not more clear despite the context?
2. Cases that are better be explicit instead of `auto`?

And with lambda functions use `auto` how these

```
auto f = [](auto v, auto x) {};
//or
std::function<void(auto v, auto x)> f;
```

Thanks...

Comment: The two  lines you provided do two very different things. Lambdas are the one case, where you actually HAVE to use auto, because their type is only know to the compiler. [This](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) imight be interesting for you.

Comment: @MikeMB I don't know about that.  Neither line compiles, so they sort of do the same thing.  One line is CLOSER to compiling?  (only missing 2 characters).  The other contains fundamental misunderstandings of `auto` as of C++14.

Comment: @Yakk: You are right, that especially the function version doesn't make any sense, whatsoever. But lambdas and std::function are fundamentally different in what they represent and how they are stored. Each lambda is a function object with its own type and is created on the heap. `std::funcion` is wrapper, that can e.g. wrap different functions or function objects, as long as they have the correct interface. Most likely I also misunderstood the question, because I was focuse on when to use auto for variables, not for parameter type deduction for lambdas.

Comment: @mike lambdas do not use free store/heap storage...  not without help.

Comment: @Yakk: Sorry, its too late I meant "stack" of course

Comment: _"Have case that are more better do explict instead of auto?"_ I'm sorry I'm sure it's a language barrier but I have no idea what you're talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I have tended to use `auto` for a select few types of code:

1. Unutterable types, such as those created by lambdas:

   ```
   auto f = []() { /* some code */ };
   ```
2. iterators, since they all implement the same opaque interface. I don't care what specific type of iterator it is, just that it acts like one.

   ```
   auto it = m.find(key);
   if(it != m.end() {
       /* some code */
   }
   ```
3. if the type was already said on the same line, for example casts:

   ```
   float f = 123.456;
   /* some code */
   auto n = static_cast<int>(f);
   ```

   or similarly:

   ```
   if(auto p = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(base_ptr)) {
       /* some code here */
   }
   ```

For everything else, I will tend to be explicit.

Regarding `std::function` vs `auto`, I will use `auto` when I can, and then will fall back on `std::function` as needed. This is because `std::function` has a slight overhead since it is implemented using type-erasure techniques.

This usually means that I will use templates to implement functions which accept a "callable thing" when reasonable as well.

That being said, if I need to store a function, possibly pass it around, then `std::function` is a great fit.